# To show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{1}{x^{1-1/p}}\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$ via Holder's inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I'm trying to solve the following problem but I'm stuck at one point.

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p[0,\infty)$. Show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\cfrac{1}{x^{1-1/p}}\int_0^x f(t)dt=0.$$

And a hint is given: first assume f has compact support.

So far, I've applied Holder's inequality and have got:

$$\left\lvert\cfrac{1}{x^{1-1/p}}\int_0^x f(t)dt\right\rvert\leq\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^pdt\right)^{1/p}$$

I'm stuck here and unsure how to proceed. How do I make the term on the right arbitrarily small? As $x\to\infty$, it seems the term on the right approaches the $p$-norm of $f$, which has no reason to be $0$. Moreover, I don't know how to use the hint. Any help with this problem is appreciated.

P.S. Interestingly, I first misread the problem as $x\to 0$ and proved that that is actually true.

Comment: first prove the result when f is compactly supported. Don’t use Holder for this because as you saw, that is a dead end. Then approximate f by compactly supported functions.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: This has some other similar solutions but the broad idea is the same imo